# Get lexeme of a composite rule in ANTLR3

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

Let's say I've something like:

```
rule:  (rule2 | rule3) {;}; //How can i get at this point rule2 or rule3 text?
rule2: HELLO+;
rule3: WORLD*;
```

I want to get the rule2 or rule3 text but all i get is a `type_return` that only gives me a `start` and a `stop`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rule
  :  r=(rule2 | rule3) {String txt = $r.text;}
  ;
```